# Проблема с aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, функции, aiogram, telebot

```
def handle_text(message):
if message.text.strip() == 'Погода на тиждень' :
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введіть назву свого села чи міста') 
       bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_week) #переход на некст функцию после отработки

def input_week(message):
           url = "https://ua.sinoptik.ua/погода-" + message.text
           r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)
           html = Bs(r.text, 'html.parser') 
           for el in html.select('#bd1'):
               day = el.select('p', class_="date dateFree")[0].text
               t_min = el.select('.temperature .min')[0].text
               t_max = el.select('.temperature .max')[0].text
```

Теперь вопрос как мне реализовать переход с функции на другую функцию как в коде "telebot" но на "aiogram" типа есть ли аналог  bot.register_next_step_handler буду благодарен за ответ и прошу не судить строго если вопрос будет тупой, я не шарю сильно. А и да код для внимания как пример.

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class STEP_HANDLER(StatesGroup):
    step_1 = State()
    step_2 = State()


assync def handle_text(message):
if message.text.strip() == 'Погода на тиждень' :
      await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введіть назву свого села чи міста') 
      await STEP_HANDLER.step_1.set()

async def input_week(state = STEP_HANDLER.step_1)
    url = "https://ua.sinoptik.ua/погода-" + message.text
           r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)
           html = Bs(r.text, 'html.parser') 
           for el in html.select('#bd1'):
               day = el.select('p', class_="date dateFree")[0].text
               t_min = el.select('.temperature .min')[0].text
               t_max = el.select('.temperature .max')[0].text
```

https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]